# Tarfile stops after first regular file

Tags: python, tar

I have `.tar.bz2` files with lots of small `json` files. A single archive might have about thousands of them, and the jsons are small (below 10kB, usually below a kilobyte too). As a result, a single archive after compression does not exceed 100kB.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/tarfile.html), the following function should return an iterator over all regular files in a tar file, returning their tarinfo structure and data.

```
import tarfile

def tariter(filename):
    with tarfile.open(filename) as archive:
        while True:
            tarinfo = archive.next()
            if tarinfo is None:
                break

            if tarinfo.isreg():
                handle = archive.extractfile(tarinfo.name)
                data = handle.read()
                handle.close()

                yield tarinfo, data
```

However instead of that, it just returns an iterator which returns its first file (together with contents), and then stops. Apparently, `archive.next()` returns None after reading the second member, even though the archive has lots of files.

Do I have a bug somewhere in this code?

Comment: Are you sure `archive.next` returns None? This could also be failing on `tarinfo.isreg()`, if that's false, it may enter a spinloop until `break` is called.

Comment: Yep, I added a `print` statement to debug it. Also, it's documented that `archive.next` should return `None`, but only when it reaches the end of archive… also, `isreg()` is there only to filter out directories because it doesn't make sense to read their contents, as far as I know it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I just tried this code locally and I'm getting the same results as you are. This is a contract issue, and you sparked my curiosity :) i'll see what i can find out

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use `extractfile` with the tarinfo directly instead of the name. This works:

```
def tariter(filename):
    with tarfile.open(filename) as archive:
        while True:
            tarinfo = archive.next()
            if tarinfo is None:
                break

            if tarinfo.isreg():
                handle = archive.extractfile(tarinfo) # LINE CHANGED
                data = handle.read()
                handle.close()

                yield tarinfo, data
```

As for *why* this is happening: `TarFile.next()` does *not* implement the iterator protocol because it returns `None` rather than raise `StopIteration`.

There are two parts to the iterator protocol: an "outer" part on the container element that returns an iterator, and an "inner" part which is the iterator itself.

The container must implement `__iter__()`, which returns a *new* object which is the iterator. `TarFile.__iter__()` returns a new `TarIter` object.

The iterator itself (`TarIter`) implements `__iter__()` (which always returns `self`) and `next()`. It must also have its own independent index to the item in the original container. This allows you to produce several different iterators over the same container without the separate iterations messing each other up.

`TarFile.next()`, however, does *not* use a separate index for its iteration, so if anyone else uses the pseudo-iteration protocol provided by `TarFile` they will mess up the iteration.

This seems to be what is happening here. `TarFile.extractfile(filename)` looks for a matching file in the current `TarFile` using `TarFile.next()` instead of `TarFile.__iter__()` which is what you were using. This corrupts the "next item" index, causing `archive.next()` to return `None` after the first `extractfile()` call.

However, if you use `extractfile(tarinfo)`, the `tarinfo` object has enough metadata in it for `TarFile` to extract the string contents without seeking through the `archive` object looking for a matching filename. Consequently, `archive.extractfile(tarinfo)` is probably faster than `archive.extractfile(tarinfo.name)`.

In general, collection objects (like `TarFile`) should *not* iterate themselves but produce a new object to iterate over them. The mere existence of a `TarFile.next()` smells of bad design. Perhaps there is a good reason for it, but *you* don't have to use it!

Do this instead:

```
def tariter(filename):
    with tarfile.open(filename) as archive:
        # use TarIter object for iteration over archive
        for tarinfo in archive:
            if tarinfo.isreg():
                handle = archive.extractfile(tarinfo)
                data = handle.read()
                handle.close()
                yield tarinfo, data
```

This is clearer, and I'll bet it's a little faster too.

Comment: And is at least documented. Thank you.

Comment: @liori, I added a long explanation of why this is happening and some alternative code you should use.

Comment: You are right that the 2.7 `tarfile` docs do not explicitly say "`TarFile` supports the iterator protocol". However, `TarFile` has an `__iter__` property and the [second code example](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tarfile.html#examples) says `for tarinfo in members:`, demonstrating its use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `next()` is failing (failed for me locally as well), but this works (and looks cleaner):

```
import tarfile

def tariter(filename):
    with tarfile.open(filename) as archive:
        for tarinfo in archive:
            if tarinfo.isreg():
                handle = archive.extractfile(tarinfo.name)
                data = handle.read()
                handle.close()

                yield tarinfo, data
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't state that TarFile objects support the iterator protocol…

Comment: The doc page gives examples of this usage, however

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest's sake changing the original OP code to the following works, although @upside code makes more sense.

```
import tarfile
def tariter(filename):
    with tarfile.open(filename) as archive:
        it = archive.__iter__() # CHANGE
        while True:
            tarinfo = it.next() # CHANGE
            if tarinfo is None:
                break

            if tarinfo.isreg():
                handle = archive.extractfile(tarinfo.name)
                data = handle.read()
                handle.close()

                yield tarinfo, data
```

Comment: The default is to perform autodetection, and it works, because it can read the first member.

Comment: OK - my bad I'd had similar issues ages ago where the read gave a single entry. Perhaps it was a case of Cargo Cult Programming on my part.